# Deploying HA Vault To GKE - dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: connect: connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, hashicorp-vault

As per the official documentation (https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/kubernetes/kubernetes-google-cloud-gke), the following works as expected:

```
helm install vault hashicorp/vault \
    --set='server.ha.enabled=true' \
    --set='server.ha.raft.enabled=true'
```

I can then run:

```
kubectl exec vault-0 -- vault status
```

And this works perfectly fine.

However, I've noticed that when if I don't have raft enabled, I get the *dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: connect: connection refused"* error message:

```
helm install vault hashicorp/vault \
    --set='server.ha.enabled=true'
```

I'm trying to work out why my Vault deployment is giving me the same issue.
I'm trying to deploy Vault into GKE with auto-unseal keys and a Google Cloud Storage backend configured.

My values.yaml file contains:

```
 global:
  enabled: true

  tlsDisable: false

  injector:
    enabled: true
    replicas: 1
    port: 8080
    leaderElector:
      enabled: true
    image:
      repository: "hashicorp/vault-k8s"
      tag: "latest"
      pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    agentImage:
      repository: "hashicorp/vault"
      tag: "latest"
    authPath: "auth/kubernetes"
    webhook:
      failurePolicy: Ignore
      matchPolicy: Exact
      objectSelector: |
        matchExpressions:
        - key: app.kubernetes.io/name
          operator: NotIn
          values:
          - {{ template "vault.name" . }}-agent-injector
    certs:
      secretName: vault-lab.company.com-cert
      certName: tls.crt
      keyName: tls.key

  server:
    enabled: true
    image:
      repository: "hashicorp/vault"
      tag: "latest"
      pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    extraEnvironmentVars: 
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: /vault/userconfig/vault-gcs/service-account.json
      GOOGLE_REGION: europe-west2
      GOOGLE_PROJECT: sandbox-vault-lab
    volumes:
    - name: vault-gcs
      secret:
        secretName: vault-gcs
    - name: vault-lab-cert
      secret:
        secretName: vault-lab.company.com-cert
    volumeMounts: 
        - name: vault-gcs
          mountPath: /vault/userconfig/vault-gcs
          readOnly: true
        - name: vault-lab-cert
          mountPath: /etc/tls
          readOnly: true
    service:
      enabled: true
      type: NodePort
      externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
      port: 8200
      targetPort: 8200
      annotations:
        cloud.google.com/app-protocols: '{"http":"HTTPS"}'
        beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"http":"config-default"}}'
    ha:
      enabled: true
      replicas: 3
      config: |
        listener "tcp" {
          tls_disable = 0
          tls_min_version = "tls12"
          address = "[::]:8200"
          cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
        }
        storage "gcs" {
          bucket     = "vault-lab-bucket"
          ha_enabled = "true"
        }
        service_registration "kubernetes" {}
        # Example configuration for using auto-unseal, using Google Cloud KMS. The
        # GKMS keys must already exist, and the cluster must have a service account
        # that is authorized to access GCP KMS.
        seal "gcpckms" {
          project     = "sandbox-vault-lab"
          region      = "global"
          key_ring    = "vault-helm-unseal-kr"
          crypto_key  = "vault-helm-unseal-key"
        }
```

Something here must be misconfigured, but what, I'm unsure.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Even after configuring Raft, I still encounter the same issue:

```
raft:
      enabled: true
      setNodeId: false
      config: |
        ui = false
        listener "tcp" {
          # tls_disable = 0
          address = "[::]:8200"
          cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
          tls_cert_file = "/etc/tls/tls.crt"
          tls_key_file = "/etc/tls/tls.key"
        }
        #storage "raft" {
        # path = "/vault/data"
        #}
        storage "gcs" {
        bucket     = "vault-lab-bucket"
        ha_enabled = "true"
        }
        service_registration "kubernetes" {}
```

Comment: What are you using for the gossip protocol if not Raft?

Comment: @MattSchuchard - I didn't realise that was a thing; as you can tell, I'm quite new to Vault, etc. I've edited the original question with my Raft config.

Comment: any in the logs? might be backend storage configuration issue

Comment: >Google Cloud Storage backend configured, when using google cloud storage why you need enable raft? raft is for node level persistent storage

Comment: @Adiii - Actually, yes; there were a number of 403 errors regarding the storage. For some reason, the change I made with the permissions with the GUI didn't take. Now I can confirm the storage is working; I just can't connect due to a certificate error now :)

Comment: @Adiii - So, would it be safe to ignore Raft completely then? Do we need something to manage the "gossip protocol"?